# How to connect TestFairy with android application?

Tags: android, testfairy

I need some clarification about ***TestFairy*** . I gone through about TestFairy that is the puprose for invite the tester for test the application as well as invite the applicatio to install the application to friends from our contact list. Is there any way that is code or project is availavle for from android application connect with ***TestFairy*** . Kindly please let me know thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TestFairy is 3-parts solution: you have the distribution (upload an apk and send it via email or community pages,) you have the insights sdk (which captures screen and records a video, including logs and coverage,) and the feedback (shake device to notify the developer, integration with CRM and bug systems.)

For using all 3, all you need to do is upload an APK to TestFairy via the web, or using the tools from the footer (Gradle plugin, Jenkins, Travis or shell script.)

If your app is using multidex, you will be told that the Insights SDK is not included. Then you need to add the SDK yourself. You can find documentation and link to the JAR file at http://docs.testfairy.com

Hope this helps!